Can one justifiably believe in the correctness of a mathematical theorem without relying on empirical evidence?
How can I justifiably believe that a theorem is correct?

Option 1: By trusting the testimony of one or more reliable mathematicians who claim to have peer-reviewed and verified the theorem's correctness.
Option 2: By personally reviewing the proof of the theorem step by step, using my own cognitive faculties, possibly with the aid of tools such as pen and paper or a computer.

In Option 1, my belief is based on the direct experience of hearing or reading the mathematicians' testimony.
In Option 2, my belief arises from engaging in the mathematical process myself, essentially conducting an "experiment" within the rules of mathematics to confirm the theorem (i.e., playing the game of mathematics, as one would also play a game of chess, go, etc., with its own rules dictating how one is supposed to play "correctly").
Both options involve empirical evidence: in Option 1, the evidence comes from my experience of the mathematicians' testimony, while in Option 2, it comes from my own experience of verifying the proof firsthand. Thus, empirical evidence is present in both cases.
I don't see how one could possibly get around this. Empirical evidence to me seems inescapable. And yet, several answers such as this one suggest otherwise. So it's possible that I may be missing something quite obvious.
How exactly can one bypass the need for empirical evidence in order to have a justified belief in the correctness of a mathematical theorem?

Perhaps you find a way to leave your own body into some much more lean body only consisting of theorem verification programs?...

@user80226 This point of view is not convincing for me. Accordingly, already understanding the mathematical theorem had to rely on empirical evidence. Because normally one has to learn from others what the actual mathematical conjectures and theorems are. - Please distinguish between what is relevant for a consideration and what not. The use of paper and pen - don't forget eraser - is not relevant in the present context. Relevant is thinking, understanding and logical reasoning.

@JoWehler If the reasoning is performed by a brain, the experiment is being run on a brain. If the reasoning is performed by a computer, the experiment is being run on a computer. I elaborate more on this here: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/117544/80226

How are you defining "emperical evidence"?  Its typically defined in a way to exclude concepts like math.

@JMac I'm defining empirical evidence as any information coming from the real world that you can be made aware of through your senses, with or without the aid of technology to amplify your senses.

Aren't mathematical theorems base on axioms? They can't exist in a void.

"Engaging in the mathematical process myself is essentially conducting an "experiment"" is your personal redefinition of "experiment". On the usual meaning of the term, verifying a proof is not an experiment. And since anything we communicate involves shared 'experiencing' of some sort your preferred 'definitions' of "empirical" and "experiment" trivialize the question.

Potential dupe of (or at least related to) questions about whether a priori knowledge exists? https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/57105/does-a-priori-knowledge-exist-and-can-we-prove-objectivity-through-it
https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/102039/can-there-be-such-a-thing-as-pure-a-priori-thinking

This sounds like a semantic dispute over the meaning of the term empirical evidence.

This is misrepresenting the linked answer. It clearly considers "empirical evidence" to be different from checking a proof. "claims about what conclusions follow from mathematical axioms can be evaluated based on logical proofs, without resort to empirical evidence." (Emphasis mine)

A Theorem is true by definition. You don't need any evidence whatsoever to justify it being true. What you need to do, is check if a proposed theorem is actually a theorem. Which, involves all kinds of justifications ranging from - if there was a flaw someone would have found it to - it's self evidently true, to having a proof checker. To checking yourself, Whether, these kinds of justifications are 1) themselves valid, and 2) use empirical evidence - is a vague question, and are probably better served as stand alone questions.

A question for you: If checking a proof constitutes empirical evidence, what ISN'T Empirical Evidence? If your definition includes all evidence, then one cannot bypass it, unless we allow for justifications which don't need any evidence whatsoever.

@MichaelCarey I would say a priori knowledge is not based on empirical evidence.

All -- proofs can be erroneous.  Or unclear.  Or the reader may misunderstand it.  Establishing that a mathematical proof is actually logically correct, IS an empirical process, for which we rely upon a consensus of mathematicians.  This process is complexified by the infinity of different logics that one can apply to the checking process.  To be fully clear, a math proof needs to cite its assumed logic system it is referencing.  That the math then applies or not to any aspect of this world -- is a different and also empirical question.

To make a point, there's a difference between a mathematical proof (which appears to be what you're talking about) and a mathematical model (sometimes also called a theory). Examples of the latter are Dark Matter and Wormholes, which only exist in mathematical models (so far) and have no scientifically-valid empirical proof (e.g., a cup full of dark matter upon which we can experiment with repeatable results and observations).

When I was at school, demonstrating the correctness of a mathematical theorem necessarily relied on empirical evidence. Was it different for you?
It was necessary to show that the theorem worked for three specific instances, as well as in general theory.
Is working through 'three specific instances' empirical evidence? Was that different for you?

First, to situate this: in essence this is a question of whether humans can have a priori knowledge. If humans can have a priori knowledge, then one needn't invoke empirical evidence to be convinced a mathematical argument.
So one simple argument would be to just invoke the idea that our intuition for reason and logic is somehow inbuilt--we know how to reason because "logic" is something inherent and inherently accessible to us. (This presumably goes back to pre-Socratic philosophy, but we could certainly gesture at Plato's forms. If the mathematician is directly accessing non-empirical things, then they don't need empirical proof.)

A potential refinement to this is the analytic-synthetic division. Propositions that depend only on their own meaning are said to be analytic. E.g. "If a man is married, he is not a bachelor" is claimed to be analytic, since a proper understanding of "marriage", "bachelorhood" (plus "if", "not", and so forth) make the answer inherent to the question.  Propositions that depend on facts about the world are synthetic. E.g. "There are at least 1000 married people in the world" requires knowing not just definitions, but also facts about the current state of the world.
Now we're free to say: Absolutely, one does not know what "3" is when one is born! We learn about "3" by counting on our fingers, and seeing 3 dogs, and so on. But, once one comes to understand the meaning of "3", then the truth-value of a proposition like "3 + 3 = 6" is contained entirely within the meaning of the proposition.
So that way, reviewing the proof of the theorem step by step isn't using empirical evidence to check the theorem. It's that you are using empirical evidence to understand which particular a priori proposition you are considering. (And if one were to be fully convinced that "11 x 11 = 111", then we might frame that as misunderstanding the meanings involved in the proposition.)
In that framing, it certainly requires empirical knowledge to know what we're being asked to reason about. But the knowledge itself, once we've correctly apprehended the meanings involved, does not require empirical evidence.

Finally, maybe the issue is with "justifiably believe". It's possible that we can justifiably believe while leaving some potential that we're wrong.

"I believe my proof is sound, because I checked it over twice completely. BUT, I did pull an all-nighter, so it's possible that none of it makes sense"

In that, I'm certainly admitting that my brain might be a faulty instrument. (I might also admit the option that I have popped into being with false memories of going over the proof to my satisfaction. Or the option that, despite logic and math working for me every prior moment, they have spontaneously decided to fail me.)
But at the same time, [to some degree of certainty or satisfaction] I believe (and am justified in believing) in the correctness of the proof. The reasons I might be wrong are empirical (I remember not sleeping last night). But the reasons I'm invoking for my belief itself are, potentially, non-empirical.

(I personally come down strongly with the "obviously everything is rooted in empirical evidence" camp + particularly think Quine's argument against the analytic-synthetic division is correct. But... as a heuristic or something, mathematical arguments seem "more a priori" than other things--they are nicely self-contained in a way that e.g. "Bob is a plumber" resists being reasoned about in the same abstract sense)

I'm not going to downvote because this is relatively well reasoned. But some challenges: the synthetic-analytic divide is dead according to Quine and others. (See his Two Dogmas. And, the idea that we don't know what the concept of 3 is before we acquire language is also incorrect according to scientific reading of numerosity. My dog knows three bones is better than 1 despite not having a grammar or being taught a number system...

In fact, some researches call this faculty the approximate number system. Lastly to critique, "it certainly requires empirical knowledge to know what we're being asked to reason about." Reason can happen independently of knowledge in the general case, because reason is inference based on belief rather than knowledge. Again, dogs can reason about bones without language, and without language, there is not justification at least on the traditional JTB interpretation. But I'll upvote because of the general thrust of your logic...

@JD Yeah, like I said, I side with Quine (and you) here. Also, a lot of that comment sounds like the start of a good answer in it's own right!

You needn't respond. I was just raising and preserving a conceptual objection in the spirit of the dialectic for the OP, particularly that there are a priori structures of mind for perception, math, and logic upon which a posteriori language acquisition functions, an easy to experience example of which is subitization. (These posts are collective property and are often pedagogical in a preliminary way.)

Logical reasoning is not within the standard conception of empirical evidence. Working through the logic of a mathematical proof is not relying on empirical evidence.
Just because you might use your senses to receive the expression of the theorem into your brain (e.g. to use your eyes to read the symbols off of a page), that does not make the reasoning that follows based on "empirical evidence."

that does not make the reasoning that follows based on "empirical evidence." - How is this any different from playing a game according to predefined rules and observing empirically what happens? Proving a theorem is basically playing the game of math, just like you can play the game of chess, go, street fighter, etc. If math does not involve empirical evidence, then figuring out how to beat the final boss in Mario does not involve empirical evidence, or figuring out how to cook a dish does not involve empirical evidence.

@user80226 forgive me for acting all "tone police" but. A suggestion: In my view, when you ask a "what am i missing about this belief i disagree with" question, you should expect that you may not agree entirely with any of the answers, but i think it's probably best to take a tone less argumentative than "citation needed". (you're not trying to win a debate)

"Logical reasoning is not within the standard conception of empirical evidence." - A citation supporting this specific statement would be highly appreciated.

Each of us has faulty reasoning.  Checking reasoning is a collaborative process, and the conclusion we reach is based on a consensus of how to reason properly.  Therefore a priori claims are empirically checked against our collaborative reasoning skills.  See Mauro ALLEGRANZA's answer

I think the OP's thesis is that learning how to "work through the logic of a mathematical proof" is an empirical process -- the teacher's instructions and the examples you work with are empirical.

It seems like the scope of this question goes far beyond mathematics. You cite the process of

personally reviewing the proof of the theorem…using my own cognitive faculties

and characterize it to be a type of experiment (thus the resulting knowledge is “empirical”)
If you step back for a second, what I think you’ll realize is that you’ve defined “experiment” in such a way that all thought is a kind of “experiment”. Now, I’m not sure I agree with that definition. But if we take it at face value, and couple it with the fact that any knowledge is necessarily arrived at through a process of thinking, then it’s just true by definition (your definition of “experiment”) that all knowledge is gained via “experiments” and is thus “empirical.”
So, is all thought a form of “experiment”? I would disagree (but I could probably be persuaded otherwise)

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Yes a theorem is correct, i.e. free of errors, when we have a proof of it, and a proof is an open (published) event. It is surveyable.
Of course, what counts in order to be accepted as such is the peer-review by the community of mathematicians, but everyone can read the proof printed on a textbook or journal and check it.
See Yuri Manin, A Course in Mathematical Logic for Mathematicians (2010), page 45 :

A proof becomes a proof only after the social act of “accepting it as a proof.”
This is as true for mathematics as it is for physics, linguistics, or biology. The
evolution of commonly accepted criteria for an argument’s being a proof is an almost untouched theme in the history of science. In any case, the ideal for what constitutes a mathematical demonstration of a “nonobvious truth” has remained unchanged since the time of Euclid: we must arrive at such a truth from “obvious” hypotheses, or assertions that have already been proved, by means of a series of explicitly described, “obviously valid” elementary deductions.

See also Wittgenstein's Philosophical Investigations (1953), II.xi (page 226).

Yes, because each of us has faulty reasoning.  Checking reasoning is a collaborative process, and the conclusion we reach is based on a consensus of how to reason properly.  Therefore a priori claims are empirically checked against our collaborative reasoning skills.

You are confusing the roles of your senses in learning about mathematics and the properties of mathematics itself. If, necessarily by empirical means, you learn the axioms and rules of mathematics, you can in principle work out no end of theorems entirely in your head.

Each of us has faulty reasoning. Checking reasoning is a collaborative process, and the conclusion we reach is based on a consensus of how to reason properly. Therefore a priori claims are empirically checked against our collaborative reasoning skills.

What a strained objection!


Can one justifiably believe in the correctness of a mathematical theorem without relying on empirical evidence?

Empirical evidence is required when the mathematics are used to model a physical system.
The mathematical equation E=mc^2 is a trivial mathematic equation that requires no evidence but the modeled relationship between Energy and mass that the equation represents must have empirical evidence to be justified.

The “correctness” of a mathematical theorem depends on whether the theorem is logically implied by the axioms of mathematics. And the truth of whether this is implied or not has no dependence on “empirical” evidence.
Regarding the axioms themselves, they are unprovable, but it’s not just that: it may make no sense to talk about proof here in the first place. It’s like asking how to prove the axioms of logic. The very notion of proof presumes logic and hence you would be asking a circular question if you asked that.

"And the truth of whether this is implied or not has no dependence on “empirical” evidence" - This would make sense if this truth exists in some Platonic realm. But in order for you to be convinced of the theorem personally, you need to go through empirical evidence as far as I can see. My question is about how you personally can be convinced of the truth of a theorem, and how you can do that without resort to empirical evidence.

@user80226 As long as you accept the axioms, then the truth logically follows, since a theorem is just an implication of the axioms and nothing else

But in order for you personally to be convinced you need empirical evidence. That's the whole point of my question. It's an epistemological question about how concrete people become convinced. I'm not asking whether there is a Platonic realm in which these mathematical truths exist independently of any minds.

@user80226 Typically, doesnt someone doing math think about the answer in their head?  When you do math, you only use senses as an auxiliary tool.  If you write down a math problem, reading it doesnt give you the answer.  You need to convert what you see into mental representations (which is basically automatic), and then it's your own thoughts to come to conclusions about the meaning behind it.  Your thoughts about what you see do the convincing with math

@JMac This is a good objection. It depends on the nature of the mind, I suppose. If the mind reduces to the brain, then the convincing is done by the brain, mostly subconsciously as you correctly point out, but once you become conscious of the outcome of the reasoning, you are essentially observing the conclusions that your brain arrived at subconsciously without your control. Now, if you believe in mind-body dualism and free will and similar ideas, perhaps the story of what's actually going during the convincing might be completely different.

@user80226 "observing the conclusions that your brain arrived at subconsciously without your control" is not a sense though by any typical definition of the word.  It's thought, which is pretty explicitly not "sensory".

@JMac Relevant question: Are thoughts qualia?

@user80226 Qualia are not the same as senses.

@user80226 you are simply asserting that one needs empirical evidence for something to be convinced by it. I am convinced that I am conscious and I am convinced that 2 + 2 = 4 given the axioms of mathematics. I do not gather empirical evidence for being conscious. The very act of observation presumes consciousness.

@Syed "I am convinced that 2 + 2 = 4 given the axioms of mathematics."  - But presumably you were not born with this belief as a baby. You acquired this belief as you were growing up and gaining experience, didn't you?

@JMac each of us has faulty reasoning. Checking reasoning is a collaborative process, and the conclusion we reach is based on a consensus of how to reason properly. Therefore a priori claims are empirically checked against our collaborative reasoning skills.
